# Mouth only Sound Design

Tags: sound-design, voice, art

I often and frequently use my own voice for sound design (and music) in many different aspects, not just human or animal interactions, but for example I was working on one short film that was on the virge of art-film/short film. No real story just an emotion. 
And I got down to business, started foley recording and in one scene the main character opens a cabinet. I just couldn't get that cabinet door to sound right. I wanted it to have a creak and something "outer-worldly", so what I ended up doing was recording me just imitating the door and combining it with the real creak, and it just worked totally right.

Soooo... What about making a film with sound design entirely created with voices? Has anyone seen anything like that? Is it possible? Would it be fun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a film, but two words...Michael Winslow

Comment: Yeah I've been watching all of his work, he's amazing! This clip gets me every time: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8auGAJrnpY4&feature=related

Comment: The only reason to watch police academy

Answer (score 1):

Not a movie, but you should really give a listen to "A Prairie Home Companion" on National Public Radio (US).  They do a couple of radio drama segments and their sound FX guy does the majority of his FX with his mouth...and it is fantastic.

Comment: They do a weekly radio show -- I actually caught it today, and it sounded like Garrison Keilor was just making stuff up to see if the sound guy could do it.  

"Then he rode up a ramp, on a motorcycle. He was chopping an onion, and peppers, and he had a frying pan where he put all those things and two eggs..."

Comment: You can listen to any of their old shows here: http://prairiehome.publicradio.org

Answer (score 1):

check out DubFx
[youtube]WhBoR_tgXCI[/youtube]

and Beardyman

[youtube]VQqTsMKa7ow[/youtube]

Even Gabriel Iglesias-the standup comedian creates police car siren effects using his mouth!! cools stuff!!

[youtube]GqJatXhQkfk[/youtube]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a WHOLE movie, but the alien probe sound in Star Trek IV was actually director Leonard Nimoy on a stage doing the effect with his voice -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a short animation done entirely with voice/mouth sound effects - it was great (no link, sorry). It was somewhat abstract, but there was a good variety of sound - you wouldn't have guessed it was all done with the mouth without knowing.

As a side note, mouth effects are great for making cartoony pops!

Answer (score 0):

Native Instruments makes a mouth controlled synthesizer.  I havn't seen it or used it even read a review.  It frequently pops up as an advertisement when I am surfing the web.

Ben Burtt used his mouth to make the noise of R2D2 so theres proof that it can work.